# How do you make a conditional statement In Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm confused on how to make conditional statements. I just can't seem to figure it out. In the example bellow I want the shoot input to only work if the user chose in this case the gun earlier in the game. Same with the knife and so on.

```
def chap4():
print "You feel around the room.\n"
time.sleep(3)
print "You find a small chest...\n"
time.sleep(3)
print "You open the chest...\n"
time.sleep(2)
print "[pickaxe, shovel, lighter, axe, 9mm(0), knife]\n"
    while (True):
        chest = raw_input("What will you take?: ")
        if chest == "pickaxe":
            print "You take the pickaxe"
            break
         elif chest == "shovel":
            print "You take the shovel"
            break
        elif chest == "lighter":
            print "You take the axe"
            break
        elif chest == "9mm":
            print "You take the empty 9mm pistol"
            break
        elif chest == "knife":
            print "You take the knife"
            break
        elif chest == "axe":
            print "You take the axe"
            break 
        else:
            print "Invalid choice. Try again..."
chap4()

def zombie():
    print "A zombie is seem in the distance"
    while (True):
        attack = raw_input("> ")
        if attack == "shoot":
            print "Zombie hp 50/100"
        elif attack == "stab":
            print "Zombie hp 70/100"
        else:
            print "Invalid input. Try again..."
```

So as you can tell by the code in having trouble... I originally thought maybe I'd make another if statement within the if statement but I'm not sure. Please help if you can... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend putting a `conditional if`

```
def chap4():
    ....
    return(chest)
def zombie()
    weapon = chap4()
    if weapon == "9mm":
        if attack =="shoot":
            print(...)
        elif attack =="stab":
        ...
```

And so on. 
So specify the weapon in the conditional in `zombie()`. Also, `zombie()` will have to know the `chest` variable, so`return(chest)` at the end of `chap4()` function, and call `chap4()` within `zombie()`

EDIT: when calling `chap4()` in `zombie()`, it needs to called a variable, in this case, `weapon`

Answer (score 1):

You can store what chest cointain like this:

```
chestContainer= {"pickaxe": "pickaxe", "shovel": "shovel", "lighter": "lighter", "9mm(0)": "9mm(0)", "knife": "knife", }
```

And then you can print the option like this:

```
print chestContainer[chest]
```

And you can evaluate if the input is valid like this:

```
if chestContainer[chest] == None:
   print "Invalid choice. Try again..."
```

**Edit:**

As user908293 said you have to save what weapon you chose.

```
weapon = chestCointainer[chest]
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional statements are fine, so far as they go.  The problem is that you aren't saving the outcomes anywhere. Do something like

```
if chest == "pickaxe":
    print "You take the pickaxe"
    weapon = "pickaxe"
elif chest == "shovel":
    print "You take the shovel"
    weapon = "shovel"
etc.
```

When the user choose an attack mode, you can check that he has the appropriate weapon:

```
if attack == "shoot":
  if weapon == "9mm":
     print "Zombie hp 50/100" 
  else: 
     print "you don't have a pistol"
```

Here too, printing is probably not enough.  You'll want to keep track of what's happened, I would think

Comment: When I run it that way I'm Getting a error telling me weapon is not defined?

Comment: @Python-Pygames-help.me That's because, as I say in my answer, the chest/weaspon isn't defined in `zombie()`, it's defined in `chap4()`. So you need to enter `return(chest)` in `chap4()` and call `chap4()` in `zombie()` See my edited code